# How do VoIP calls get through a firewall

Tags: networking, voip, firewall

I installed an Obi100 (VoIP device with RJ11 to connect normal phones) behind my router, which has UPNP disabled and no ports forwarded. Somehow, it still receives VoIP calls and I am confused how that works.

I was getting a bunch of spam phone calls that weren't even going through my voip provider, so I think they were able to send the calls directly to my Obi100. I fixed that with a special filter rule in the Obi100, but I don't even see how someone could contact the Obi100 from outside anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Obi devices use Google TCP based APIs to send/receive calls instead of SIP which is what many would assume when they hear VoIP. You were probably receiving inbound calls to your google account once they see you are "online" when your obi device connects with google. The setting probably disables announcing your availability.